# Jquery autocomplete expanding too wide

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete

I'm using the autocomplete function from jquery, but long strings are causing the suggestion box to expand wider than the input field. You can see it in this image.

[image: too wide suggestions list]

In the above image, the "(1450)" should be placed on the next line.

My jquery function:

```
function autosuggest() {
    $( autocomplete_field ).autocomplete(
    {
         source: posturl,
         minLength:2,
         delay: 0
    });
};
```

CSS:

```
.ui-widget-content { background: #ffffff; }
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible { position: absolute; left: -9999px; }
.ui-autocomplete { border: 1px solid #abadb3; border-top: none; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; cursor: pointer; }
* html .ui-autocomplete { width:1px; } /* without this, the menu expands to 100% in IE6 */
.ui-menu-item { list-style:none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-bottom:1px dotted #000; }
.ui-menu-item a { display: block; padding: 6px; }
.ui-menu-item:last-child { border-bottom:none; }
.ui-menu-item  strong{ color: #003b63; }
.ui-state-focus { background-color: #aad9fb; color:#000; display: block; }
```

In the jquery function, I tried adding:

```
$('.ui-menu').css('max-width','178px')
```

This worked for the field in the screenshot, but I have many autocomplete fields on my website with different width, so that's not an option.

I've searched the documentation of the API, but couldn't find a solution yet.

Comment: Did you try using jquery to get the width of the input and setting the max width of the autocomplete to the width of the input?

Comment: var width = $("#city_textbox").innerWidth();
$('.ui-menu').css('max-width',width); this does work, but the input fields have different names.

Comment: Replaced it with var width = $(".ui-autocomplete-input").innerWidth(); and seems to work for all autocomplete fields.

Comment: Happy to hear that =) If you don't mind i add an answer so you can accept it =P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try getting the width of the input fields, then change the max width of the autocomplete to that width.